# Change all values in $3 to zero

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file that looks like this:

```
2360 111037877 111105745 111161458
505 111128359 111026865 111006164 
375 117170057 0 0
247 117086016 0 0
613 117030996 117010050 117029287
```

I want to change all the values in column 3 to zero so that the file looks like this:

```
2360 111037877 0 111161458
505 111128359 0 111006164 
375 117170057 0 0
247 117086016 0 0
613 117030996 0 117029287
```

How can I do this? I know this is a very basic question but I can't do it with awk. I was trying to do something like this:

```
awk '{$3 = 0}' old file > new file
```

and

```
awk '$3 == "*" { $3=0}' old file > new file
```

Answer (score 5):

Your first try was almost good, you just forgot to print the line:

```
awk '{$3 = 0; print}'
```

A shorter version of the same thing:

```
awk '{$3 = 0}1'
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to `print $0`

```
% awk '{$3=0;print $0}' inp.txt 
2360 111037877 0 111161458
505 111128359 0 111006164
375 117170057 0 0
247 117086016 0 0
613 117030996 0 117029287
```